# Get EAN by Amazon ASIN

Tags: amazon-product-api

Amazon API is so complex and huge, so I've spent some time to understand how to get EAN by ASIN or even if it is possible or not. I was trying to use GetItems and it works but `ItemInfo` doesn't have EAN field.
Any help, please!